# Java int[] vectors are giving me points instead of data.

Tags: java, eclipse, vector

I am working with vectors and when I copy the data and try to edit it the vector and the copy both change.

```
//The vectors contains int[] and the first 3 are loaded with int values.
int ToCheck[] = OpenSet.elementAt(Current);
ToCheck[1] = ToCheck[1] + 1; // This changes OpenSet and ToCheck[].
boolean IsInVector = false;

for(int y = 0;y < OpenSet.size(); y++){
     if(ToCheck == OpenSet.elementAt(y)) // Because it changed both values it always is true
     {
    IsInVector == true;
     }
}
```

I want to be able to copy the data in the vector and edit it without changing the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way to copy an array is to use `Arrays.copyOf`:

```
int[] tmp = openSet.elementAt(current);
int toCheck[] = Arrays.copyOf(tmp, tmp.length);
```

And while you are listening, **PLEASE** learn to use the accepted Java naming conventions.  Method names and field/parameter/local names should start with a lower-case letter.

Comment: Thank you it seems to work, one thing it should be Arrays not Attays.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a full copy of the array:

```
int[] origArr = OpenSet.elementAt(Current);
int[] newArr = Arrays.copyOf(origArr, origArr.length);
```

another (unrelated) point - please follow Java's naming conventions, which is lower case at the beginning of variable names.